# Node doesn't receive message, but rostopic list/info sees it

Tags: ros, message, network, rostopic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've modified the turtlesim tutorial to control some servos from a ps3 controller, and everything works fine when everything is running from my laptop. Now I want to move the part/file that actually do the moving of the servos over to a RPi.

I've added

> export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://Yoda.local:11311

to the .bashrc on both nodes.

rostopic list/info/type displays the same info on both laptop and RPi, but when I try to get any actual data out, the RPi doesn't receive anything on rostopic echo/hz

I've tried running

> rostopic pub -r 10 /robonova3/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: 0.1, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}'

on both machines, but its only picked up locally, not by the other machine...

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227064/node-doesn%27t-receive-message,-but-rostopic-list/info-sees-it/) by [Pengatom](https://answers.ros.org/users/25765/pengatom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-02-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-02-18**:
Have you also set the ROS_IP on both computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can happen when ROS_IP or ROS_HOSTNAME (only one of the two needed) are not set correctly on both machines. See also [lEnvironmentVariables](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables) or this [Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/9915/ros-mutiple-machine/), Searching for "ROS_IP" or "ROS_HOSTNAME" here or on google should also provide sufficient info to fix this issue.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pengatom](https://answers.ros.org/users/25765/pengatom/) on 2016-02-19**:
Voila! Thanks
Should've been better explained that this is needed. In the tutorial it's only mentioned as something to add if one cannot ssh to the machine - which I could...

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-02-25**:
you are welcome to edit the wiki to better explain that ;)